# React - Using a custom hook to call another hook - a clean approach?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-apollo

I'm writing an app in React, using next.js.

I have a GraphQL query I need to execute - I just want to execute it and get the result, however having issues.

So if I have call the `useQuery` hook like below, it returns the response:

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo';

export function LaunchesFunctionTwo() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_SUBSCRIPTION_BY_ID)

  // I see the data I want returned here ok
  console.log(data)

  // I don't need to display anything I just want the data - hence this empty string
  // Infact, thats probably a second question, how can I just use useQuery on its own
  return ''
 
}
```

However if in the Index component, I do the same, the console.log(data), returns undefined , so like so:

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo';

export default function Index(props) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_SUBSCRIPTION_BY_ID)

  // Doing this however returns me undefined
  console.log(data)

   return (<div>...</div>)
}
```

UPDATE:
I got this working. I read that one of the only 2 places we can use Hooks is: `Call Hooks from custom Hooks`.

So I made a custom hook like so:

The `use` keyword is required according to docs:

```
export function useLaunchesFunctionTwo() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_SUBSCRIPTION_BY_ID)

  return data
}
```

Then in my index.js I can simple call that `useLaunchesFunctionTwo` to get my data.

So the question now - is this a valid way of working. Are could I have organised my code a little clearer?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Isn’t useQuery async?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not importing useQuery in Index

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo';
```